# What is the max number of attachable volumes per Amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, volume

I am running Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS as the guest operating system.

How many volumes can I attach to an instance? I'm working on a project which will require that each of our customers have their own volume.

Amazon seems to not have dynamic volumes, so we need to create a new volume from a snapshot to grow an existing one. This operation requires server down time and that's unacceptable. This is why we need one volume per client. With a physical server, I'll put a 2TB drive and use quotas, but we don't want to go this way for now.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://serverfault.com/questions/359705/how-many-ebs-drives-i-can-mount-on-a-single-ec2-instance-using-amazon-web-servic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact there is no limit if you stick with Linux (Windows instances are limited to 16 EBS volumes). You may have to change the naming of the devices, then you can get easily up to 24 volumes:

```
/dev/sdf1  /dev/sdf5  /dev/sdf9  /dev/sdg4  /dev/sdg8  /dev/sdh3
/dev/sdf2  /dev/sdf6  /dev/sdg1  /dev/sdg5  /dev/sdg9  /dev/sdh4
/dev/sdf3  /dev/sdf7  /dev/sdg2  /dev/sdg6  /dev/sdh1  /dev/sdh5
/dev/sdf4  /dev/sdf8  /dev/sdg3  /dev/sdg7  /dev/sdh2  /dev/sdh6
```

For further information take a look at the docs: [Attaching the Volume to an Instance](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-attaching-volume.html?r=5444).

Comment: in windows2003 can i attach more than one ebs volume?. I already attached 1 TB ebs volume to my ec2 instance. Now i tried to attach the second ebs volume with 1 TB size which was created from snapshot to ec2 instance but it shows disk as dynamic and when i right click on the device it shows only two options.
1. Import foreign disks
2. convert to basic disk
So, any idea how to attach the seconds ebs which was created from snapshot?.

Comment: @loganathan I have no clue ... Sorry, but I'm not working with Windows anymore. You should open a new question for your issue.

Comment: Per current http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/device_naming.html this information is valid only for instances whose virtualization type is Paravirtual. For HVM, the scheme is slightly different.

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer is wrong. There is a limit. I have direct experience right now with EC2 t3.medium, m5a.large, c5.xlarge, running under Amazon Linux, here is what I found:

- there seems to be a hard limit of 26 volumes
- the device names are /dev/sd[a-z], /dev/xvd[a-z], /dev/xvd[a-z][a-z]

The [Amazon Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/nvme-ebs-volumes.html) says indirectly that the limit is (currently) 26 devices:

> EBS volumes are exposed as NVMe block devices on Nitro-based
>   instances. The device names are /dev/nvme0n1, /dev/nvme1n1, and so on.
>   The device names that you specify in a block device mapping are
>   renamed using NVMe device names (/dev/nvme[0-26]n1). The block device
>   driver can assign NVMe device names in a different order than you
>   specified for the volumes in the block device mapping.

So, while you can generate tons of device names with /dev/xvd?? that will actually work, and they don't have to be in any order, and you can mix and match all the combination, e.g., /dev/sdf, /dev/xvdz, /dev/xvdxy, there is still a limit of 26 devices.

What happens if you go beyond this limit? Two things:

- If the instance is running, the volume you are trying to attach will remain stuck in "attaching" state.
- If the instance is stopped, the volume attaches without problem, but when you try to start the instance, it will get stuck in "pending" state.

Because of this behavior, I doubt that the issue is about the OS, Linux, Windows, FreeBSD, whatever. If it was about the OS, the instance would enter "running" state and then get stuck on boot, but wouldn't get stuck in "pending".

Also, you may want to list your /dev/ directory to see for yourself, but you do not have to worry about those nitro device names /dev/nvme* and wonder how they are mapped from the device names that you specified in the attach-volume command; you will find both, i.e, in the above example, you will find the device names /dev/sdf, /dev/xvdz, /dev/xvdxy, as is, but you also find the /dev/nvme* nodes. You can use the device names that you specified during the attach-volume command for things like mkfs, and, I strongly recommend, you then use the UUID=... format to specify the volumes in your /etc/fstab, and never try mounting by /dev/ node name.

Comment: If you've experienced this does that mean the AWS documentation is incorrect? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/volume_limits.html

Comment: At the time I wrote this answer it was correct, as I run all my instances as plain Amazon Linux. You could not get past 26. Since the issue is one of the VM, not of the OS (in case of Unix anyway) Amazon can always have changed those limits in the meantime.

I also checked the documentation I quoted at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/nvme-ebs-volumes.html and it has not been updated.

Comment: I came back here searching Google for a problem I had with an EC2 not starting (stuck in pending state) only to find out that I had the same problem 2 years ago. This is to confirm that the 26 device limit still exists today.

Answer (score 2):

AWS says that there is a limit of 40 volumes for linux and 26 or 16 for Windows with this caveat for each.
Attaching more than * volumes to a * instance is supported on a best effort basis only and is not guaranteed.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/volume_limits.html

Comment: not true, it's 26. I tried it 2 years ago and just a month ago again.

Answer (score 1):

To build on moosgummi's answer, AWS allows for a wide range of block device names. See the relevant documentation here, under "Specifying a Block Device Mapping."

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/block-device-mapping-concepts.html

An EBS volume mount point must begin with /dev/, and then specify "hd" or "sd" (2), then a through z (26), and then 1 through 15, or a no number (16). Those choices yield 2 x 26 x 16 = **832 name options**. (More than moosgummi's suggested 24.) But be careful to avoid conflicts with the root device (sda1), or other defaults (sda[1-15]).

Device name limitations are the only constraint I know of on total number of attached EBS volumes. But I've never tried more than a few at once.

Comment: you may not *know* other constraints, but there is a hard 26 device constraint. Try it out and you will see. Quickly launch an AMZ Linux instance and attach 27 EBS devices to it and notice it will not start (stuck in "pending" state). Then remove device attachments one by one and you see it will start at 26.

Comment: This only applies to a Nitro instance, which support a maximum of 28 __attachments__. This means that each ENI attached reduces the number of volumes that can be attached and have the instance launch successfully. This is not the case for Xen, which does not use shared device pools, and has a soft limit of 40 __volumes__ (which is not affected by network interface attachment).

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers above are entirely correct, and it's partly due to the behavior of the two different virtualization platforms.

The reality here is that this behavior differs between **Xen** based instances (4th generation and earlier) and the newer **Nitro** based instances (5th gen an onwards).

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/volume_limits.html) doesn't disambiguate between Xen and Nitro behavior very well here, so for clarity:

**For Nitro instances**

- A maximum of 28 **attachments** is supported. Note that this is all devices, *not just volumes*. The docs do a fairly good job of covering this.
- Technically this means that there is a maximum of 27 volumes, on an instance with a single ENI.

**For Xen instances**

- A soft maximum of 40 **volumes** is supported. You can definitely attach more volumes than this (I've seen 98 volumes attached to instances, but it's not guaranteed to be reliable, and I'd strongly recommend not going down this road).
- Xen doesn't have the same shared device pool model as Nitro does

There are other limits that apply:

- The maximum number of encrypted EBS volumes that can be attach concurrently (I can't find any public docs for this off hand, but I've seen this limit hit)
- Performance limitations based on the bandwidth available and the number of volumes attached (the docs recommend a limit of 8 volumes, which seems sane to me)